# How to conditionally render a surrounding box when revealing otherwise hidden objects in R Shiny?

Tags: css, r, shiny, conditional-formatting, shinyjs

In the below simplified code, I use `shinyjs` to jointly show and hide text and table output. The text output is "Test show/hide in JS", the table output is a portion of the Iris data. By default, when invoking the App, the objects are hidden. Click "Show!" to reveal the objects, click "Hide!" to hide them. I would like to encircle both of the objects when revealed in a box as shown in the image below, although I'll try alternatives too like shading instead of a box to see which looks better. Any recommendations for how to do this? My guess is some type of CSS wizardry but maybe there's an easier way. Though if CSS is the only option I can swallow that pill too.

[image]

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

toggleView <- function(input, output_name){
  observeEvent(input$show, {show(output_name)})
  observeEvent(input$hide, {hide(output_name)})
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(), 
  br(),
  actionButton("hide","Hide!"),
  actionButton("show","Show!"),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(2,h5(hidden(textOutput("text")))),   
    column(6,hidden(tableOutput("table")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderTable(iris[1:5,1:3])
  output$text <- renderText("Test show/hide in JS")
  toggleView(input, "table")
  toggleView(input, "text")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add another `column` and provide it with a `border`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  radioButtons(
    inputId = "show",
    label = NULL,
    choices = c("show", "hide"),
    selected = "hide"
  ),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    conditionalPanel(
      "input.show == 'show'",
      column(4,
             column(4, h5(textOutput("text"))),
             column(8, tableOutput("table")),
             style = "border: 2px solid grey; margin-left: 15px;"
      ),
      style = "display: none;"
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderTable(iris[1:5, 1:3])
  output$text <- renderText("Test show/hide in JS")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

PS: There is no need to use `shinyjs`.

Comment: Thank you ismirsehregal! The code I posted is simplified; in the larger code it derives from I need to retain something like action buttons and not the materialSwitch.  I'm trying out shinyWidget's radioGroupButtons() where one button is for "Show", the other is "Hide", this would work.  I haven't got it working yet.

Comment: @Village.Idyot please see my edit using `radioButtons`.

Comment: Yes, radioButtons() looks excellent. Perfect solution

Comment: @Village.Idyot btw: are you aware of the function [shinydashboardPlus::box()](https://rinterface.github.io/shinydashboardPlus/articles/improved-boxes.html)?

Comment: Never heard of it, I'm reading through it thanks!